# Magento flat indexer doesn't copy 'image' attribute to catalog_product_flat table

Tags: magento, flat

I am using Magento Community 1.7.0.2.

Recently I decided to turn on 'Use Flat Catalog Category' and 'Use Flat Catalog Category' options in my store. All images on my frontend that were using 'image' attribute disappeared (they were replaced by default image placeholder). All images that are displayed with 'small_image' or 'thumbnail' attribute displays correctly.

I looked into catalog_product_flat_1 table and there is no 'image' column there (but there 'image_label' column...). I looked into the flat indexer code and was able to print the SQL statement that is using to get all attributes that are inserted into flat table:

```
SELECT `main_table`.*, `additional_table`.* 
FROM `eav_attribute` AS `main_table` 
INNER JOIN `catalog_eav_attribute` AS `additional_table` 
ON additional_table.attribute_id = main_table.attribute_id 
WHERE (main_table.entity_type_id = :entity_id) AND (main_table.backend_type = 'static'     
OR additional_table.is_used_for_promo_rules = 1 OR additional_table.used_in_product_listing = 1 OR additional_table.used_for_sort_by = 1 
OR main_table.attribute_code IN('sku', 'type_id', 'name', 'status', 'visibility', 'price', 'weight', 'url_path', 'url_key', 'thumbnail', 'small_image', 
'tax_class_id', 'special_from_date', 'special_to_date', 'special_price', 'cost', 'is_recurring', 'recurring_profile', 'msrp_enabled', 'msrp',
'msrp_display_actual_price_type', 'enable_googlecheckout', 'gift_message_available', 'price_view', 'price_type', 'shipment_type', 'weight_type', 
'sku_type', 'links_purchased_separately', 'links_title', 'short_description', 'image_label', 'thumbnail_label', 'small_image_label', 'news_from_date',
'news_to_date', 'created_at', 'updated_at', 'required_options'))
```

As you can see no 'image' attribute on the list.

The 'image' attribute is used in frontend in default Magento distribution, so I'm wondering is this a bug?

Answer (score 6):

I just spent some time figuring out this issue as well and here is the solution that I found is most clean and uses Magento's XML-style abstractions to add the `image` column to the `catalog_product_flat_1` table:

In config.xml:

```
<config>
    <frontend>
        <product>
            <collection>
                <attributes>
                    <image />
               </attributes>
            </collection>
        </product>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

Then reindex your flat catalog tables (Admin > Index Management > Select All + Reindex) and clear all Magento caches.

Answer (score 5):

While @Jordi Buj's answer will work, it is not very sustainable. 
For example, if you reuse that code on another Magento instance, it will likely not work until someone follows the steps described to get image included in the flat table.

A more correct, code-based way of doing this, is to add the following to your Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection:

```
->joinAttribute('image', 'catalog_product/image', 'entity_id', null, 'left')
```

instead of the typical:

```
->addAttributeToSelect('image')
```

Whereas the latter will simply add 'image' to the columns to SELECT (which won't help, since it's not a column in that flat product table), the former will explicitly join with the image attribute from the EAV tables.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Joining the attribute defeats the purpose of the flat table.

Answer (score 2):

I just came to this issue the other day. Same Magento version (1.7.0.2) although different symptoms.  I was actually seeing the images correctly on my site. My problem was that my custom reports with number of products (total, active, without description/shortdescription, without images/small/thumbnails) started to give incorrect results and found that it was since I activated flat product tables.

It turns out that the Magento API (Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()) automatically uses the flat tables, and there isn't the same amount of information there, but only the one strictly necessary.

For instance, not all attributes are copied, but only those that are classified as "Used in product listing".
In my case, both description and image were not copied, so I went to the admin and set to Yes "Used in product listing" for both.

In case of the image it wasn't quite easy, as its "Catalog input type for store owner" (Media image) effectively hides the "Used in product listing" field. So I needed a browser developer tool (like Firebug or Chrome Dev tools) to first remove the disabled="disabled" HTML attribute from the "Catalog input type for store owner" field, and change it to some other value. Now the "Used in product listing" field is visible, set it to Yes. And finally revert the "Catalog input type for store owner" value back to "Media image".

If you inspect the flat table (catalog_product_flat_) then you'll see the image and description attributes and you.

This process worked for me. I then rechecked my catalog listings and similar pages just to avoid any nasty side effect... 
Hope it works for you

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be resolved by running the following code:

```
$attributeId = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute')->getIdByCode('catalog_product','image');

if ($attributeId) {
    $attribute = Mage::getModel('catalog/resource_eav_attribute')->load($attributeId);
    $attribute->setUsedInProductListing(1)->save();
}
```

I have chosen to do it by creating a a data upgrade script in one of my local modules. Consult **Data script** section of this article for more information on how to create a data upgrade script: http://inchoo.net/magento/magento-install-install-upgrade-data-and-data-upgrade-scripts/